# How do I coalesce a sequence of identical characters into just one?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have this:

My---sun--is------very-big---.

I want to replace all multiple hyphens with just one hyphen.

Comment: Do you really want to coalesce only hyphens, or any run of duplicate characters?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import re

astr='My---sun--is------very-big---.'

print(re.sub('-+','-',astr))
# My-sun-is-very-big-.
```

Comment: +1, but `-{2,}` would avoid replacing single `-` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to replace *any* run of consecutive characters, you can use

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "AA---BC++++DDDD-EE$$$$FF"
>>> print(re.sub(r"(.)\1+",r"\1",a))
A-BC+D-E$F
```

If you only want to coalesce non-word-characters, use

```
>>> print(re.sub(r"(\W)\1+",r"\1",a))
AA-BC+DDDD-EE$FF
```

If it's really just hyphens, I recommend unutbu's solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you really only want to coalesce hyphens, use the other suggestions.  Otherwise you can write your own function, something like this:

```
>>> def coalesce(x):
...     n = []
...     for c in x:
...         if not n or c != n[-1]:
...             n.append(c)
...     return ''.join(n)
...
>>> coalesce('My---sun--is------very-big---.')
'My-sun-is-very-big-.'
>>> coalesce('aaabbbccc')
'abc'
```

Comment: +1 for a general solution. Since the OP used English words in their example, specifying a set of characters to coalesce (or not coalesce) would probably be preferable so as to avoid mangling words with double letters (i.e. letters -> leters).

Comment: Agreed on the +1 for a general solution

Answer (score 5):

As usual, there's a nice `itertools` solution, using `groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'aaaaa----bbb-----cccc----d-d-d'
>>> ''.join(key for key, group in groupby(s))
'a-b-c-d-d-d'
```

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the question if you only want to dedupe the hyphens.  Is there an itertools solution that would keep 'aaaaa'?

Comment: @McPeterson: Sure, but they're not as nice.  For just handling hyphens, you can do `''.join(key if key == '-' else ''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(s))`.  For handling any non-alphanumeric character, `''.join(''.join(group) if key.isalnum() else key for key, group in groupby(s))`.  But I'd just use one of the regex solutions instead.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("-+", "-", "My---sun--is------very-big---.")
'My-sun-is-very-big-.'
```

the regular expression `"-+"` will look for 1 or more `"-"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub('-+', '-', "My---sun--is------very-big---")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an alternate without the re module:

```
'-'.join(filter(lambda w: len(w) > 0, 'My---sun--is------very-big---.'.split("-")))
```

Or going with Tim and FogleBird's previous suggestion, here's a more general method:

```
def coalesce_factory(x):
    return lambda sent: x.join(filter(lambda w: len(w) > 0, sent.split(x)))

hyphen_coalesce = coalesce_factory("-")
hyphen_coalesce('My---sun--is------very-big---.')
```

Though personally, I would use the re module first :)

- mcpeterson

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is the String object's replace function.

```
while '--' in astr:
    astr = astr.replace('--','-')
```

Comment: This will be very ineffective in case of large text.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
    my_string = my_string.split('-')
    my_string = filter(None, my_string)
    my_string = '-'.join(my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
my_str = 'a, b,,,,, c, , , d'
```

I want

```
'a,b,c,d'
```

compress all the blanks (the "replace" bit), then split on the comma, then if not None join with a comma in between:

```
my_str_2 = ','.join([i for i in my_str.replace(" ", "").split(',') if i])
```